# ContentControl with controls around the content

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm wanting to create either a custom `ContentControl` in WPF that can contain one element. This is easy enough, I've done it plenty of times. But here I want the content control to have rulers on the bottom and left edges. I want these controls to be accessible from the code behind. I'm at a loss with how to move forward. I've considered a template but then the ruler controls would not be readily accessible. I also thought about creating a `UserControl` with a content like dependency property, but then the XAML would not be as simple for the user of this control as just using a content control.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say you want those controls to be accessible from code behind ?

Comment: I want to be able to access the ruler controls in C# code of my custom ContentControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template parts. You can have a look at a complete example on this page :

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

From the example, here is how the `CustomControl` declares template parts :

`[TemplatePart(Name = "UpButtonElement", Type = typeof(RepeatButton))]
  [...]
  public class NumericUpDown : Control
  [...]`

And how you can access them :

```
  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        UpButtonElement = GetTemplateChild("UpButton") as RepeatButton;
        [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is to be able to use content in the two different ways it is commonly used, but at the same time with one control. You can do this, but just need 2 different content properties. You could define your own secondary content property set but it's much easier to just derive from `HeaderContentControl`, which already does exactly that for you with its `Header` properties.

To allow users of the control to treat it like a normal `ContentControl` and just enclose content in the tags you can use the `Header` content as the part that you define `UserControl` style and can access from code-behind. Inside that content you can just put a `ContentPresenter` wherever you want to receive the external `Content`. You then also need to adjust the `ControlTemplate` to only show the `Header` content (`Content` will be inside the `Header` part remember).

```
<HeaderedContentControl x:Class="WpfApp.MyRulerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp">
    <HeaderedContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyRulerControl}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </HeaderedContentControl.Template>

    <HeaderedContentControl.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <Border x:Name="Ruler1" Height="20"/>

            <ContentPresenter
                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyRulerControl}}, Path=Content}"
                ContentTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyRulerControl}}, Path=ContentTemplate}"/>

            <Border x:Name="Ruler2" Height="20"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HeaderedContentControl.Header>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

Now you can use the control like normal:

```
<local:MyRulerControl>
    <TextBlock Text="External content here"/>
</local:MyRulerControl>
```

You can also get to anything inside that `Header` section from code-behind:

```
    public MyRulerControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Ruler1.Background = Brushes.Red;
        Ruler2.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
```